# How to set a CSS class name comes from an array of json object inside ngFor | Angular 6

Tags: css, loops, class, angular6, ngfor

I have a loop where i display dynamically icons, the position of the icons are styled by `css` on `style.css`, but the classes name are actually an elements of json object.

**The problem** is how to use the value of the json element which is `style` in order to style the icons.

**The *ngFor**  looks like this:

```
  <div *ngFor="let count of counters; let i = index"  class="{{count.style}} dispanserDiv ">
      <span class="dispLabel"> {{count.name }}</span>
    <img (click)="openStockModal(stockModal)" class="dispanser" src="../assets/icons/dispanserIcons/0.png">
  </div>
```

[image: When i insepct to check the value,the desired classes are set whith the value as exactly as i want, but when i hard coded the classes it works fine]

also i tried [ngClass] but not working, any help is appreciate.

Comment: Do you mean the value of the json element is a classname or a style like {'width': '100%,', height':'500px'}"?

Comment: @Igor Carvalho yes that what i meant

Comment: Did you try to use [ngStyle]?

Comment: @Igor Carvalho no, but does this attribute take a class name or a css code?

Comment: [ngStyle] can take a css code. use [ngClass] for a class name.

Comment: @Igor Carvalho hey i think my code was working but displaying the icons somewhere out of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after i opened the inspect element, and i hover over the tags i found on screen a title message with a direction arrow out of the height of the scree, so i changed the `margin-top` attr th icon appear again.

but i am pretty sure that when i set the class name without using the json element value, it display fine, but when i use the json element the icons appear at a different position, but i have no idea why this is happening. but it finally worked